# wordpress menu - assign specefic class of list to anchor

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to assign specefic class in  menu list to its child anchor.

for example:

```
<li class="icon-home list-item">
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
</li>
```

I want to convert above output to this (Remove class icon-home from list and assign it to its child anchor):

```
<li class="list-item">
    <a class="icon-home" href="index.php">Home</a>
</li>
```

**What I want to do ??**
Search for matching class `icon-` in wordpress menu array, then set it to its child anchor and then unset it from list.

I am using a code which search for a class `divider` in menu array and then convert it to a new list with class="divider". Here is that code:

```
// managing divider: add divider class to an element to get a divider before it.
$divider_class_position = array_search('divider', $classes);
if($divider_class_position !== false){
    $output .= "<li class=\"divider\"></li>\n";
    unset($classes[$divider_class_position]);
}
```

Here is my all code for wordpress menu override, Please have a look before answering:

```
<?php

/**
 * Extended Walker class for use with the
 * Twitter Bootstrap toolkit Dropdown menus in Wordpress.
 * Edited to support n-levels submenu.
 * @author johnmegahan https://gist.github.com/1597994, Emanuele 'Tex' Tessore https://gist.github.com/3765640
 */
class NavMenuWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {


    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth ) {

        $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
        $submenu = ($depth > 0) ? ' sub-menu' : '';
        $output    .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu$submenu depth_$depth\">\n";

    }

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {


        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $li_attributes = '';
        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

        // managing divider: add divider class to an element to get a divider before it.
        $divider_class_position = array_search('divider', $classes);
        if($divider_class_position !== false){
            $output .= "<li class=\"divider\"></li>\n";
            unset($classes[$divider_class_position]);
        }


        $classes[] = ($args->has_children) ? 'dropdown' : '';
        $classes[] = ($item->current || $item->current_item_ancestor) ? 'active' : '';
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
        if($depth && $args->has_children){
            $classes[] = 'dropdown-submenu';
        }


        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names . $li_attributes . '>';

        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ($args->has_children)        ? ' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= ($depth == 0 && $args->has_children) ? ' <b class="caret"></b></a>' : '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;


        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }


    function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) {
        //v($element);
        if ( !$element )
            return;

        $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];

        //display this element
        if ( is_array( $args[0] ) )
            $args[0]['has_children'] = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
        else if ( is_object( $args[0] ) )
            $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
        $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $element, $depth), $args);
        call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'start_el'), $cb_args);

        $id = $element->$id_field;

        // descend only when the depth is right and there are childrens for this element
        if ( ($max_depth == 0 || $max_depth > $depth+1 ) && isset( $children_elements[$id]) ) {

            foreach( $children_elements[ $id ] as $child ){

                if ( !isset($newlevel) ) {
                    $newlevel = true;
                    //start the child delimiter
                    $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $depth), $args);
                    call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'start_lvl'), $cb_args);
                }
                $this->display_element( $child, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth + 1, $args, $output );
            }
            unset( $children_elements[ $id ] );
        }

        if ( isset($newlevel) && $newlevel ){
            //end the child delimiter
            $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $depth), $args);
            call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'end_lvl'), $cb_args);
        }

        //end this element
        $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $element, $depth), $args);
        call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'end_el'), $cb_args);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look for:

```
$item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
```

and replace it with:

```
$item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .' class="'.$classes[0].'">';
```

Now it changes `<li class="icon-home list-item">` to `<a href="index.php" class="icon-home">`

Comment: thanks fro answer, but what happen if there is already a class in `$attributes` and will your code just assign class starting from `icon-` or every class in list?? please describe it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

On $attributes just display Link active and hover effect no one specific class define in link .